# Build Primefaces 11.0.0: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision

Tags: primefaces

Tried to build primefaces 11.0.0, got the following error:

```
 mvn clean install

[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ primefaces-parent ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.DefaultArtifactInstaller
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting: private org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver.logger
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionRangeResolver
    for parameter 2 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.DependencyCollector
    for parameter 5 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.DefaultArtifactInstaller
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger field org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionRangeResolver.logger to org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.slf4j.Slf4jLoggerFactory
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanPropertyField.set(BeanPropertyField.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:129)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:129)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:107)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:129)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:129)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:107)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:129)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:129)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:129)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:129)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:464)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:119)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: try to use a newer maven version

Comment: thanks. using the latest mvn resolved the issue.